# Postgres or CouchDB for a movie database rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, couchdb

I'm developing a streaming service comparison app. Basically I'm using some rest api to grab movies available on various streaming platform because I want to create a comparison system.

I'm struggling about the platform: my Rails app now has a PostgreSQL DB: I have to manage users and some additional data like categories, filters, etc.

By the way all the informations I'm grabbing about a single movie are stored in a json get response. Is it possible to use a document DB (couchDB) to store only the data about a single movie, and then retrieve this

For example:

```
class NetflixCategory < Activerecord::Base

end

class NetflixMovie
include CouchPotato::Persistence

end
```

How can I retrieve all the movies that belongs to a category if I store categories using ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't go with PosgreSQL JSON and JSONB support?
You are already on PostgreSQL and you just need json support.

Why you should go CouchDB, do you plan to sync with PouchDB in the browser?

PostgreSQL give you option to have transactions and full ACID compliance, while have a json data store.
They even have a quite good option to query inside the json:

[Postgre JSON Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)